# Run SQL queries without external database

Tags: sql

I have a text file of tab separated data. Millions of rows so I can't open it in Excel.

Is there a way to use some SQL client to load the file and run queries on it without uploading the file to a database? I.e. can my local machine function as my database?

I know I could solve this with command line scripting but I'm trying to find a solution that I can then share with the accounting department and they're scared of the command line.

Comment: You could build a .net app that uses LINQ to access the file.

Comment: You can have full-blown MySQL on your local machine.

Comment: You could try using an ADO/OLEDB class to treat the flat file as a relational source.

Comment: What is the argument against using a database?

Comment: You can easily install Postgres locally

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ODBC datasource based on the Microsoft Text Driver. That driver should come pre-installed on any Windows PC. This uses the Jet Engine which is still somewhere in the Windows OS. Then you can use any Query tool (even MS Query) to analyse your data.